# React Native Tesseract OCR [Error : Data path does not exist! ]

Tags: react-native

Iam folowed tutorial from npm about react-native-tesseract-ocr and i found this error :

> OCR Error:  Error: Data path does not exist!

```
at createErrorFromErrorData (D:\React Native\alternote\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:121)
at D:\React Native\alternote\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:78
at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (D:\React Native\alternote\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:398)
at D:\React Native\alternote\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:137
at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (D:\React Native\alternote\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314)
at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (D:\React Native\alternote\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:136)
at debuggerWorker.js:70
```

this is my code :

```
takePicture = async function() {
    if (this.camera) {
        const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
        const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
        console.log(data.uri);
        this.setState({path: data.uri});
        const tessOptions = {
            whitelist: null, 
            blacklist: '1234567890\'!"#$%&/()={}[]+*-_:;<>'
        };
        RNTesseractOcr.recognize(data.uri, 'LANG_INDONESIAL', tessOptions)
            .then((result) => {
            // this.setState({ ocrResult: result });
            console.log("OCR Result: ", result);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
            console.log("OCR Error: ", err);
            })
            .done();
    }
};
```

i've put trained data to android/app/src/main/assets/tessdata/ind.traineddata because i just want to user indonesial language. but the error want gone, please help

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue...